# How does the disk seek is faster in column oriented database

Tags: performance, file-io, column-oriented, bigdata, nosql

I have recently started working on bigqueries, I come to know they are column oriented data base and disk seek is much faster in this type of databases.

Can any one explain me how the disk seek is faster in column oriented database compare to relational db.

Answer (score 1):

The big difference is in the way the data is stored on disk.

Let's look at an (over)simplified example:

Suppose we have a table with 50 columns, some are numbers (stored binary) and others are fixed width text - with a total record size of 1024 bytes. Number of rows is around 10 million, which gives a total size of around 10GB - and we're working on a PC with 4GB of RAM. (while those tables are usually stored in separate blocks on disk, we'll assume the data is stored in one big block for simplicity).

Now suppose we want to sum all the values in a certain column (integers stored as 4 bytes in the record). To do that we have to read an integer every 1024 bytes (our record size).

The smallest amount of data that can be read from disk is a sector and is usually 4kB. So for every sector read, we only have 4 values. This also means that in order to sum the whole column, we have to read the whole 10GB file.

In a column store on the other hand, data is stored in separate columns. This means that for our integer column, we have 1024 values in a 4096 byte sector instead of 4! (and sometimes those values can be further compressed) - The total data we need to read now is around 40MB instead of 10GB, and that will also stay in the disk cache for future use.

It gets even better if we look at the CPU cache (assuming data is already cached from disk): one integer every 1024 bytes is far from optimal for the CPU (L1) cache, whereas 1024 integers in one block will speed up the calculation dramatically (those will be in the L1 cache, which is around 50 times faster than a normal memory access).

Answer (score 0):

The "disk seek is much faster" is wrong. The real question is "how column oriented databases store data on disk?", and the answer usually is "by sequential writes only" (eg they usually don't update data in place), and that produces less disk seeks, hence the overall speed gain.